# sendBroadcast(intent, string) in version greater than Android 4.4

Tags: android

After reading the android documentation and many forums, here is my understanding.

`sendBroadcast(intent, string)` is usable for Android 4.4 or less. Also, it is used to "refresh" device storage whenever file is created or updated.

`scanFile(context, string)`is usable for higher Android versions (e.g. Android 5.1), and it is used to "refresh" device storage when a file is created, but **not** for modified files.

**Here is my question: Since `sendBroadcast(intent, string)` cannot be used for Android version greater than 4.4, what is a replacement method that can have the same effect?** 
(I have attempted to use `scanFile(context,string)` of course, but does not refresh when the files contents are modified.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager).sendBroadcast() as it's much more efficient and allows you to avoid thinking about any security issues related to other apps being able to receive or send your broadcasts.

This is has a number of advantages over sending
global broadcasts with `Context.sendBroadcast()`:

1. You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so
   don't need to worry about leaking private data.
2. It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to
   your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can
   exploit.
3. It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the
   system.